# Python: Read line from file, split it and change object

Tags: python, object, text-files

Let's imagine that I have a text file that contains 1000 lines. All of them look like this:

```
FirstName:SecondName:1:2:3:4
```

":" can be replaced with any other symbol, and i have list of 1000 objects:

```
class RECORD:
    FNAME = "default"
    SNAME = "default"
    M1 = 0;
    M2 = 0;
    M3 = 0;
    M4 = 0;

    def outname(self):
        print (self.FNAME + self.SNAME)

LIST = []
for i in range(1000):
    LIST.append(RECORD(i))
```

So, I want to read this file, and fill first objects with strings and integers from first line, second object with second line etc. 
How can I do that?

Comment: If `:` is replaced with, say, `/`, how would your program know? Can the symbol change for each line? Within each line?

Comment: An aside:  semicolons are unnecessary here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are looking for something like this:

```
class Record(object):
    """docstring for Record"""
    def __init__(self, FNAME, SNAME, M1, M2, M3, M4):
        super(Record, self).__init__()
        self.FNAME = FNAME
        self.SNAME = SNAME
        self.M1 = M1
        self.M2 = M2
        self.M3 = M3
        self.M4 = M4

with open('your_file_name') as f:
    LIST = [Record(*(line.split(':'))) for line in f]
```

All of the work happens in the last line. List comprehension on file gives you the list of lines. Each line is split on `:` and passed to Record constructor with unpacking.

Comment: Thanks, but what about list of objects? I have a file of 1000 lines and 1000 object. Should i put it into loop? Can i lately call any object of list, like in c++? I mean, can i call LIST[1].FNAME or something like than?

Comment: In this case LIST would contain 1000 objects of Record class. LIST[1] is an object corresponding to the second line in your file. So LIST[1].FNAME would indeed return the first name corresponding to that object.

Comment: So, does it mean i need to somehow put 'for i in range(1000):' and 'with open('marks.csv') as f:' in one loop? Or it will automatically create objects until end of file? Sorry for lame questions again.

Comment: No loop is needed. `[line for line in f]` would return a list of lines like 'FirstName:SecondName:1:2:3:4'; `[line.split(':') for line in f]` would return a list of lists, with elements like ['FirstName', 'SecondName', '1', '2', '3', '4\n']. Finally, we do `[Record(*(line.split(':'))) for line in f]`. A list of words in each line is passed to a constructor. The star is needed as constructor takes a number of arguments rather than a single list argument.

Comment: Thanks, but i think something wrong with constructor: when i start program, python says that ' NameError: name 'SNAME' is not defined'. I tried to swap it with M1 assignment, but it still angry about SNAME. When i renamed SNAME to SNAAME (in brackets and after "=") it says 'NameError: name 'SNAAME' is not defined'. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

For simple classes (like yours), `collections.namedtuple` is often useful:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Record = namedtuple("Record", "FNAME SNAME M1 M2 M3 M4")
with open("records.txt") as record_file:
    records = [Record(*line.split(':')) for line in record_file]

print records[3].FNAME  # For example
```

Additionally, you might want to store similar items as sequences, so each record is a list of names and a list of ints. Here is a version that does that.

```
from collections import namedtuple
from pprint import pprint

Record = namedtuple("Record", "names m")
records = []
with open("records.txt") as record_file:
    for line in record_file:
        line = line.split(':')
        line = line[0:2] , [int(i) for i in line[2:]]
        line = Record(*line)
        records.append(line)

print records[3].names[0] # Same as first example
pprint (records)          # pretty-print entire list
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I tried to make it quite pythonistic still close to what you know from C++. But please try to immerse yourself a little bit more in Python...

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,
                 first_name='default',
                 second_name='default',
                 m1=0, m2=0, m3=0, m4=0):

        self._first_name = first_name
        self._second_name = second_name
        self._m1 = m1
        self._m2 = m2
        self._m3 = m3
        self._m4 = m4

    def full_name(self):
        return self._first_name + ' ' + self._second_name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    INPUTFILE = 'persons.txt'
    persons = list()
    for line in open(INPUTFILE):
        first_name, second_name, m1, m2, m3, m4 = line.strip().split(':')
        persons.append(Person(first_name, second_name, m1, m2, m3, m4))
    for person in persons:
        print(person.full_name())
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import csv

class Record(object):

    def __init__(self, fname = 'default', sname = 'default', m1 = 0, m2 = 0, m3 = 0, m4 = 0):

        self.fname = fname
        self.sname = sname
        self.m1 = int(m1)
        self.m2 = int(m2)
        self.m3 = int(m3)
        self.m4 = int(m4)

    def get_name(self):
        return '{0} {1}'.format(self.fname, self.sname)

records = []
reader = csv.reader(open('file.txt', 'rb'), delimiter = ':')
for row in reader:
    records.append(Record(*row))

for record in records:
    print(record.get_name())
    #FirstName SecondName
```